# Regex Pattern to avoid : and , in the strings

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a string which comes from the DB.
the string is something like this:-

```
ABC:def,ghi:jkl,hfh:fhgh,ahf:jasg
```

In short `String:String`, and it repeats for large values.

I need to parse this string to get only the words without any `:` or `,` and store each word in ArrayList

I can do it using split function(twice) but I figured out that using regex I can do it one go and get the arraylist..

```
String strLine="category:hello,good:bye,wel:come";
        Pattern titlePattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
        Matcher titleMatcher = titlePattern.matcher(strLine);
        int i=0;
        while(titleMatcher.find())
        {
            i=titleMatcher.start();
            System.out.println(strLine.charAt(i));  
        }
```

However it is not giving me proper results..It ends up giving me index of match found and then I need to append it which is not so logical and efficient,.

Is there any way around..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String strLine="category:hello,good:bye,wel:come";
String a[] = strLine.split("[,:]");
for(String s :a)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use java [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)
Sample:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, ":,"); 
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) 
  System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient...I knew i can use tokens very easily but I think using split will be more efficient that tokens..

Comment: It depends on the length of the string. If the string is very short you can split, if it is long it is better to iterate tokens. Then with tokenizer you can skip empty tokens, for example if you have "a::b:c", during the loop.

Comment: My string can be short or can be very very long.One thing for sure the formation of the string is always the same.. String1:AssociatedString,String2:AssociatedString and so on..

Comment: If the string can be long then I prefer to use StringTokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can use a regular expression to parse the entire string at once, I think it would be less readable than splitting it with multiple steps.